# How to place \blacksquare at the end of a mathematical formula in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, symbols

At the end of a solution involving a mathematical equation, I like to place \blacksquare at the right hand side corner of the equation. I don't know how to do it. I enclose the code..
Kindly help me on this - thank you!

```
Thus, the system transfer function is given by
 $$
 G(s) = {X(s) \over U(s)} = {5 \over s^2 + 2 s + 3}   \blacksquare
 $$
```

Comment: Please check out the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Comment: Are you using plain TeX or LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible packages. For example ntheorem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
{%
\theorembodyfont{\small}
\theoremsymbol{$\square$}
\newtheorem*{Proof}{A label you want}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Proof}

  $G(s) = {X(s) \over U(s)} = {5 \over s^2 + 2 s + 3}$
\end{Proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is now [atendofenv](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/atendofenv) package for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atendofenv}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\AtEndOfEnv{equation}{$\square$}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
 G(s) = {X(s) \over U(s)} = {5 \over s^2 + 2 s + 3}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please be so kind and provide a MWE which use this package and show result of compilation.